# Call a function on href

Tags: jquery

Below is my script

```
 $('<a class="page_link" href="javascript:'+getResults('http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize=2&page=' + i)+'" longdesc="0" style="display: inline-block;">' + i + '</a>').insertBefore('.next_link');
```

Like above am trying to call a function on href attribute. But is is showing undefined on href.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you bind click event? What is your expected result?

Comment: actually am creating a anchor element in a for loop, so that i can call getResults function with page=1, page=2 like that which using i value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create HTML using jQuery and bind event using it. Refer to [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```
$('<a />', {
    'class' : 'page_link', 
    'longdesc' : 0,
    'text' : i  
}).css({
    'display' : 'inline-block'
}).on('click', function(){
    getResults('http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize=2&page=' + $(this).text());
})
.insertBefore('.next_link');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding the event on every added element, you can create one event on the container, or the body:

In the `ready` function:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.page_link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getResults('http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize=2&page=' + $(this).text());
});
```

Whenever you want to insert a new element:

```
$('<a class="page_link" href="#" style="display: inline-block;">' + i + '</a>').insertBefore('.next_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

your close, you just need to update your href to:-

```
$('<a class="page_link" href="javascript:getResults("http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize=2&page=' + i + '") longdesc="0" style="display: inline-block;">' + i + '</a>').insertBefore('.next_link');
```

you are mixing the ' & ".

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
 $('<a class="page_link" href="javascript:getResults(\'http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize=2&page='+  i+'\');" longdesc="0" style="display: inline-block;">' + i + '</a>').insertBefore('.next_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/f5xuw7ky/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('<a/>', {
    href: '#',
    class: 'page_link',
    html: 0,
    click: function() { alert("Hi"); }
}).appendTo($('#hello'));
```

Hope this will help you.

NOTE: `html` is the text you want to show a hyperlink.